# Question From Serre's "On the 2-Dimensional Modular Representations of $G(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$"

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, elliptic-curves

See page 24 at the top [here](https://aghitza.org/publications/translation-serre-duke.pdf).

We are supposing the mod $p$ Galois representation $\rho^E_p: G_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$ is reducible, so that $E$ has a $\mathbb Q$-subgroup $X$ of order $p$. In the case subgroup $X$ is acted on by the trivial character, why are we guaranteed a $\mathbb Q$-point of order $p$? Doesn't every subgroup of order $p$ have a generator, regardless of the action?

Comment: Every subgroup of order $p$ has a generator... but that generator need not be defined over $\mathbb Q$. It will be defined over $\mathbb Q$ if and only if the $G_{\mathbb Q}$ action on it is trivial.

Comment: Isn't the whole $X$ defined over $\mathbb Q$ already though?

Comment: The group scheme X is defined over Q, but a priori, its generator is defined only over the algebraic closure of Q. [A good example to keep in mind: The group of p-th roots of 1 in C is a Q-group scheme of order p, but its generator doesn't lie in Q unless p<3].

Comment: $X$ being defined over $\mathbb Q$ means that $\sigma(x)\in X$ (rather than $\sigma(x)=x$) for all $x\in X$ and $\sigma\in G_{\mathbb Q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if the representation $G_{\Bbb Q} \to \mathrm{Aut}(E[p])$ is reducible, then there is some subgroup $X \subset E[p] \subset E(\overline{\Bbb Q})$ of order $p$ (1-dimensional over $\Bbb F_p$) which is Galois-stable. This does *not* mean that $X \subset E(\Bbb Q)$ a priori.

However, if you know that the action of $G_{\Bbb Q}$ on $X$ is trivial, this means that we actually have $X \subset E(\Bbb Q)$, so necessarily $X$ contains a $\Bbb Q$-rational of $E$ of order $p$.